# Handling Redux Saga result in view from which action call originates

Tags: reactjs, promise, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm new to Redux Saga, coming from Redux Thunk.  In some situations, I need to know whether an API call fails or succeeds from inside the view from which I called the action.  With Redux Thunk, I would do something like the following.

My component and action creator would look like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.actions.fetchItems()
    .then(result => {
        if (result.status === 'OK') {
            console.log('Request succeeded, take particular action in this view')
        }
        else {
            console.log('Request failed, take other action in this view')
        }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>My view</div>
    )
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        items: state.items,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators({
            ...actions,
        }, dispatch),
    }
}


export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(MyComponent)



import * as t from './actionTypes'
import {CALL_API} from '../api'

const xhrGetItems = (params) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const action = {
        [CALL_API]: {
            type: t.XHR_ITEMS_FETCH,
            endpoint: `http://www.example.com/myendpoint`,
            method: 'get',
        }
    }
    return dispatch(action)
}
```

My API middleware catches all actions with a `CALL_API` property, uses an ajax library to make the appropriate call, then returns a fulfilled promise.  My reducer is set up to handle each of the possible states of the api call (success, failure, pending).  All the while, I can still check the result of the call in my view where it originated.

So my question is, how can this be accomplished with Redux Saga?  Right now my saga api middleware is doing everything it should be doing, but when I call `fetchItems()` in my view, the result is a plain JS object, so I can't check whether or not it succeeded.

It's possible that I'm going about this completely wrong, too.  Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common pattern with redux and redux-saga is to create 3 Actions for an API call. In your case I would create:

- LIST_ITEMS_START
- LIST_ITEMS_SUCCEEDED
- LIST_ITEMS_FAILED

Your saga would look something like this:

```
function* watchListItemsStart() {
  yield takeLatest(LIST_ITEMS_START, listItemsStartFlow)
}

function* listItemsStartFlow() {
  try {
    const result = yield call(api.getItems)

    if (result.status === 'OK') {
      yield put(LIST_ITEMS_SUCCEEDED, items)
    } else {
      throw new Error(result.error)
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(LIST_ITEMS_FAILED, error)
  }
}
```

The sagas have cleanly abstracted away the API side-effect. The reducer can concentrate on state management:

```
switch (action.type) {
  case LIST_ITEMS_START:
    return {
      ...state,
      isLoading: true,
      error: null,
      items: [],
    }
  case LIST_ITEMS_SUCCEEDED:
    return {
      ...state,
      isLoading: false,
      items: action.payload.items,
    }
  case LIST_ITEMS_FAILED:
    return {
      ...state,
      isLoading: false,
      error: action.payload.error.getMessage(),
    }
}
```

Now you have everything you need in your store that can be selected and reacted on in the component.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchItems()
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading, items, error } = this.props

    // Here you can react to the different states.

    return (
      <div>My view</div>
    )
  }
}

connect(state => ({
  isLoading: itemsSelectors.isLoading(state),
  items: itemsSelectors.getItems(state),
  error: itemsSelectors.getError(state),
}), {
  fetchItems: actions.fetchItems
})(MyComponent)
```

An important point here is, that your component gets very dumb. It just gets props and does not handle the result of the API call (no `promise.then` here).

I hope this answer will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Alex.  What you described is basically what I have set up.  My question is about how to keep the component somewhat smart.  A use case for this would be:  User posts data via api call.  On successful request, redirect user to different page/component (e.g. using react-router `browserHistory.push('/myPath')`).  Normally I would call this redirect inside the component.  Is there a better way to do this that I'm not considering?

Comment: Based on what you described and what I have set up currently, I would need to do this by checking in `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` `this.props.isLoading && !nextProps.isLoading`, then take appropriate action according to `nextProps.error` (e.g. navigate to new component on success or show error message on error).  This just seems like a long workaround for something simple.  Can you comment on best practices for this specific use case?

Comment: All your side effects like routing, api calls etc. should go into the saga. So in the saga where I check `if (result.status === 'OK')` you could put the router logic. You will make your life much easier if the components are !not smart but dumb

Comment: Thanks again @Alex.  Do you know of any real world projects/examples that are openly viewable?  [The real-world example from redux-saga docs](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/examples/real-world/containers/App.js) is pretty good but doesn't deal with any post/put/patch/delete actions.  Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: I just found the React boilerplate project from Max Stoiber that can maybe  help. It uses saga's. You can find my described pattern here: https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/containers/HomePage/sagas.js#L16

Comment: no promise.then.... this is my issue, say I have a clean redux-saga setup that allows for create user, I then want to use that returned user id, to chain an action, let's say create project, how can I do this with redux-saga, without creating a create-user-and-project action?

Comment: I might have missed something but I don't see how this works when eg. there are more than one button. Ain't there a *saga-way* of letting the component know that the actual async action it started has finished?