# How can I wait for the result of a dispatched action in redux-saga?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

How can I wait for the result of a dispatched action in redux-saga?

```
function_login = async () => {
  const test_await = await this.props.userWatcher(
      this.state.email,
      this.state.password,
  );
  console.log('test await ', test_await);
};
```

I want my `console.log` to be executed after I got the result from the `userWatcher` action, but it's not working.

Here is my action creator function and saga:

```
export function userWatcher(email, password) {
  return {type: 'USER_WATCHER', email: email, password: password};
}  

function* userEffectSaga(action) {
  try {
    let {data} = yield call(userApi, action.email, action.password);
    console.log('data user', data);
    yield put(getUser(data));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('user name effect saga ', e);
  }
}

export function* userWatcherSaga() {
  console.log('user watcher saga ');
  yield takeLatest('USER_WATCHER', userEffectSaga);
}
```

Comment: this can be help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/59841400/11982418

Comment: thank you bro, its give me some clue to workaround about redux saga.

Comment: i found alternatif solution in this link. i think this is good logic for my problem above.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43995720/9037671

Comment: ya try this out